# Why does "(sleep 10 & sleep 1); wait" return after 1 second instead of 10?

Tags: bash, wait

`wait` without arguments is supposed to wait for all child processes, however

```
(sleep 10 & sleep 1); wait
```

returns after 1 second instead of 10, and so it's failing to wait for `sleep 10` to finish.

Why is that, and how could I fix it?

Comment: `sleep 10 & sleep 1 & wait` appears to work.  I suspect it has something to do with the subshell that is created with `()`.

Comment: Note the difference in behavior between `(sleep 10 & sleep 1)` vs `(sleep 1 & sleep 10)`.  The `wait` is outside of the subshell, so it is irrelevant for this example.  The subshell exits as soon as the last command finishes.  In your example, I think the `wait` is only waiting on the subshell to finish; it doesn't have any knowledge of the two `sleeps`, all it sees is one (implicit) `sh`/`bash`.

Comment: @cdarke & != &&

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parentheses create a subshell—an entirely new shell process just for those two commands.

The `wait` command only waits for a shell’s own children (in fact, that’s all it can wait for); grandchildren don’t count. Since the `sleep` processes are children of the subshell instead of the main shell, they cannot be `wait`ed for.

Therefore, what happens is:

1. Subshell is created to run `sleep 10 & sleep 1`, and the main shell waits for it to finish

   1. Subshell runs `sleep 10`, and continues processing immediately because of `&`
   2. Subshell runs `sleep 1`, and waits for it to finish
   3. One second later, `sleep 1` exits.
   4. The subshell is out of commands to process, so quits.

      - All of the subshells children (i.e., `sleep 10`) are orphaned, and re-parented to the `init` process (*not* the original shell).
2. The main shell continues to the `wait` command.
3. Because the shell has no children, `wait` returns immediately.
4. Nine seconds later, `sleep 10` exits, and `init` cleans it up.

The only way to get `wait` to recognize a command is to not exit it in a subshell. In this example, you can achieve that by using curly braces, or by omitting the braces entirely. In either case, first `sleep 10` will be run, then `sleep 1` will be run, and when `sleep 1` finishes `wait` will run until `sleep 10` finishes.